# Windows 11 installation media not detecting any drive

Tags: windows-11, windows-installation, installation-media

I wiped out the all ssd drive. Then I created, on each of two different USB drives, a Windows installation media. Both don't find any drive during installation. Help is much appreciated.

[image: (https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg]

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Make sure CSM is enabled and the target disk has no partitions

Comment: thanks, I'll check.

Comment: For Windows 11 CSM should be disabled, enable Secure Boot and TPM, the disk must be formatted as GPT. See [Windows 11 requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/windows-11-requirements).

Comment: Have you tried loading a storage driver for your hardware?

Comment: @Nassbirne Yes it asks me to browse for a file. I don't know where to download a storage driver. Anyway it was working before with Windows 11.

Comment: [CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) should **_never_** be enabled unless needing to access a legacy OP ROM, and it should be re-disabled once done in the OP ROM _(its sole purpose was to allow EFI booting on distros that didn't support it circa <2017; since Win7, Windows has supported EFI boot)_. Please do the following: `Shift`+`F10` → `DiskPart` → `lis dis` → `sel dis #` → `clean` → `convert gpt` → Click back on the install dialogue: _Refresh_ → If that doesn't result in the SSD populating, reboot back to the installer. Is the motherboard UEFI? Is the SSD an NVMe?

Comment: @JW0914 Currently I have no Windows installation to do `Shift+F10` → `DiskPart` → `lis dis` → `sel dis #` → `clean` → `convert gpt`. I'm running Ubuntu now. Yes motherboard is UEFI and SSD is NVMe.

Comment: @the_eraser I'm confused - why this question then if there's no way to troubleshoot? For NVMe drives, there has been the occasional issue having them recognized by the installer as an installable drive due to a missing driver, however I can't recall the context. If when you attempt to install again you convert the drive's partition table to GPT and it's still not detected, searching for that may be useful

Comment: @the_eraser You need to do the steps outlined by @JW0914 in Windows setup where you took the screenshot. `SHIFT+F10` will summon the command prompt.

Comment: @Nassbirne thanks for clarifing.

Comment: @JW0914 Yes I can do the steps you suggested from the installation media.